# Kotlin: How to verify an extension function is called on a mock

Tags: kotlin, mockk, mockito-kotlin

Say I have a Java class Metrics. I defined some extension functions on Metrics in Kotlin

```
fun Merics.expose(name: String, value: Number) {
 // do something
}
```

Note that the Java class `Metrics` also has a method called `expose` but with different signature.

I created a test where I mocked a `metrics` objects and call a code path where the extension function `expose` should be called. But how can I verify that those extension functions are invoked?

I tried to use mockk and mockito-kotlin, none of them seem to know that `metrics` object has a new function called `expose` with different signatures.

Comment: The question is: Why it shouldn't be called?

Comment: The question is how I can verify that the extension function `expose(name:String, value:Number)` is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not verify that the extension function is called on your mock, as it is not part of that class. The extension function is just a top-level function with a receiver (in your case an instance of `Metrics`).

**But you can still verify that the extension function was called in your code**

You can do this using [mockkStatic](https://mockk.io/).
You are passing the the path of the (generated) extension function. Let's assume you created your `Metrics` extension function in package `org.com`. The extension class should get generated in: `com.org.MericsExtensionKt`.

A test that wants to verify the call to your extension function could look like:

```kotlin
@Test
fun check_metrics_expose_extension_was_called() {
  mockkStatic("com.org.MericsExtensionKt")

  // call your function that is calling Metrics.expose()
  // classUnderTest.someFunction()

  // this verifies a call to the extension function and their parameters
  verify { any<Metrics>().expose(name = any(), value = any()) } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing any<Metrics>? I want to use a specific mock object. And when I do use a concrete mock object, it doesn't know this metrics mock object has an `expose` function with this signature. It only knows the `expose` method from the original Java `Metrics` class.

Comment: Extension functions are static functions in Java. So you can not use a normal mock object calling that static function. The way above is working fine. You can verify any call (incl parameters to the extension (static) function you created. You can use your created mock object of `Metrics` plus the mock of the static call `expose()`.

Comment: Thanks about the static nature of extension functions. What do u mean by "... plus the mock of the static call expose()" ? I do not need to mock the extension function behavior, I wanted to verify it is called.

Comment: What I meant is that you can mock the orignal `Metrics` class, plus mock the static/extension call and verify it (as it is not part of the actual class/mock). My example above shows how to verify that your extension function was called. I really do not know how else I should demonstrate this scenario. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I slightly adjusted my answer. Hope you can use it.

Comment: Is there a way to call the mockStatic without passing the classPath as a string?

Comment: @Franz Yes! You can call `mockkStatic(MyClass::myExtFunction)`. That would be `mockkStatic(Merics::expose)` if you are going off this example.

Also I recommend using this as block `mockkStatic(MyClass::myExtFunction) { // code to test mock here }` so you don't forget to unmock it later.